# Use Git command line for a repository from within another Git repository

Tags: bash, git, shell, continuous-integration, bamboo

I'm working on a build job in Bamboo right now that conducts a few tasks (updating various dependencies) on a project in Git-repository A. This build is triggered by changes in a Git-repository B. So whenever a commit is pushed to repository B the build in repository A starts.

However, this build should only be started if the commit in repository B is made by a specific user. So in the build script of repository A I'd like to do a `git log` in repository B to check if the latest commit is done by this specific user and if not, I want to exit the script.

What I currently do is this:

```
if [ "$(git log -1 --pretty=format:'%an')" != "SPECIFIC_USERNAME" ]; then
    echo '-----THIS COMMIT IS NOT SCHEDULED FOR BUILD-----'
    exit 0
fi
```

However doing git log here, only shows me the logs of repository A although I need the log from repository B.

Can this be done somehow?

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Is `B` a subrepository of `A`? `cd` to the other repository.

Comment: No, these are 2 separate repositories, both on the same Bitbucket Server.

Comment: You cannot run commands at the remote repository. First you need to clone it locally. If you need only the last commit clone with `--depth=1 --no-checkout`.